# element pushed out of anchor

Tags: html, css

I have this weird thing happening to me.

I have a menu and I try to create a mega menu.

I`m adding a ul in anchor tag to create the mega menu but it s pushed out of it. Anyone know why?

HTML:

```
<ul class="header_menu">
<li>
    <a href="#">
        Menu 1
        <ul class="sub_menu">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </a>
</li>
```

and check this picture of html using view source.

[image using view source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12Gke.png)

The ul sub_menu is pushed out of the anchor and its placed near it, not as a parent of anchor tag.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

As Quentin said, and according to w3c "Nested links are illegal".
A more detailed explanation here: 
https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid.

See [The a element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> Content model: Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

You **cannot** have a link as a descendant of another link.

If you remove the nested link, then the problem goes away:

[image]

You probably want "Menu 1" to be a link and "Submenu" to be a different link. So end your first link **before** the nested list.

Comment: This is indeed correct. The better way to do this would be to place the anchor tag, and place the UL element NEXT to it instead of INSIDE it. Then with the + selector you can select it in CSS and style it if thats rquired.

Comment: Actually, you are very right. Thank you very much sir.